# Removing duplicate elements in array without sorting - wrong output

Tags: c, arrays, output

I have been trying to write a function to remove duplicate elements in an array of ints without sorting it.

For that task, I created a function named `removeDuplicateElements`, which gets an array and its string, and returns a new dynamically allocated array, which is a copy of the original array with removal of all duplicates elements. This function also returns by reference the size of the new array.

I also used in my code functions which build a dynamic array and print it.

Here is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printArray(int *arr, int size);
int *buildArray(int size);
int *removeDuplicateElements(int *arr, int size, int *newSize);

void main() {
    int size,newSize;
    int *arr;
    int *newArr;

    printf("please enter a number for the size of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("\nenter %d numbers: ", size);
    arr = buildArray(size);
    printf("\nthe array after removing the duplicate elements is: ");
    newArr = removeDuplicateElements(arr, size, &newSize);
    printArray(newArr, newSize);
    free(newArr);
    free(arr);
}

/* this function removes all duplicate elements in a given array */
int *removeDuplicateElements(int *arr, int size, int *newSize) {
    int *newArr;
    int count = size, i, j; 

    /* finding the new size of the original array with removal its duplicate elements */
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {  
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
            if (arr[i] == arr[j] && i != j) {
                count--;
                break;
            }
    }
    newArr = (int*)malloc(count * sizeof(int)); /* dynamically allocating the new array */

    count = 1;
    newArr[0] = arr[0];

    /*adding the elements in the new array without changing the order*/
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j] && i != j) {
                break;
            }
            if (j == size - 1) {
                newArr[count] = arr[i];
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    *newSize = count;     /* updating the size of the new array */
    return newArr;        /* returning the address of new array */
}

void printArray(int *arr, int size) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int *buildArray(int size) {
    int i;
    int *arr = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    if (!arr) {
        printf("ERROR! Not enough memory!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);

    return arr;
}
```

**I get a wrong output for that code, and I dont understand why**

For instance, for the following array with `size=5` :`1 1 3 1 3` 
I get the wrong output `1`, whereas the expected outout is 
`1 3`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `void main()`. Your nested loops are wrong, you are counting the same duplicate many times. Run the program in your head for {1,1,1} and see what `count` you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're firstly calculating the size of the new array incorrectly. For your example input, when you're looking at the first 3, it scans the whole array to see how many 3's there are and finds there are 2 and concludes it's a duplicate. It then does the exact same thing for the 2nd 3. So you end up with the size of the new array as 1.

Instead of scanning the whole array, you only want to scan the array for the elements preceding the one you're checking. So something like this.

```
for(i=1;i<size;i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        if (arr[i] == arr[j])
        {
            count--;
            break;
        }
}
```

And for the code that fills the new array has the same problem

```
for(i=1;i<size;i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        if (arr[i] == arr[j])
        {
            break;
        }
    if(j==i)
    {
        newArr[count++]=arr[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, no it works and more important - I understand where I have done mistakes.

Comment: @DonaldT It sounds as if this answer was helpful for you. If that's the case you should considering accepting it.

Comment: @4386427 I didnt know that..thank you for letting me know. I have just accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative way of doing it, ofcourse it involves modifying the original array but this is just an alternative. Basically it involves crossing off the duplicate element by replacing it with a maximum value like 0xFFFF.

```
int* removeDuplicateElements(int *arr, int size, int *newSize)
{    
int *newArr;
int count = size, i, j;
int index = 0;

/*finding the new size of the original array with removal its duplicate elements*/

for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    for (j = i+1; j < size; j++)
        if (arr[i] == arr[j] && arr[i] != 0xFFFF)
            {
                count--;
                arr[j] = 0xFFFF;

            }

}

printf("Size is %d \n", count);

newArr = (int*)malloc(count * sizeof(int));      /*dynamically allocating the new array*/

for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    if(arr[i] != 0xFFFF)
    newArr[index++] = arr[i];
}

*newSize = count;     /*updating the size of the new array*/
return newArr;        /*returning the address of new array*/
```

}